# How to read the path from text file and each file from the location and copy and paste to target folder

Tags: shell

I have the text file(Result.txt) with following details:

Result.txt

/Demo/sample/src/applications/Admin_Util.app
/Demo/sample/src/analyticSnapshots/View_Snapshot.snapshot

Each line represents path for each the file.Files are exist in the folder sample/src (path of source C:/Test/sample/src) and I want to copy each file from the above path and paste it in the destination directory (path of destination directory is C:/Test/target/src

I need to remove /Demo and go to sample/src and copy the first file Admin_util app and paste this file in C:/Test/target/src

can you please help with shell commands to copy and paste the each file into other directory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: each line represents the path of the file and I need to read this path from the text file and go to that path. Please help me with shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do what you need

```
#!/bin/ksh
File="/path/to/your/file/Result.txt"
DestDir="C:/Test/target/src"
while IFS= read line
do
    #cp "$line" "$DestDir"
    cp "${line#/Demo}"  "$DestDir"

done <"$File"
```